How to resolve TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object with node.Js
I want to create a program where if the value of 'Bab': null, then babParagraph will not appear. However, when I create the following conditional statement, I encounter an error message saying 'Cannot convert undefined or null to object'.
ps: im using docx
here my code snippet:
let babParagraph = null; // Initialize babParagraph with null

        // check if item.bab isn't null
        if (item.bab !== null) {
            // if item.bab isn't null, create babParagraph
            babParagraph = new Paragraph({
                children: [
                    new docx.TextRun({
                        text: 'Bab ' + item.bab,
                    }),
                    new docx.TextRun({
                        text: '\nKetentuan Umum',
                        break: 1,
                    }),
                ],
                alignment: AlignmentType.CENTER,
            });
        }

and then error appear:
var _name = Object.keys(value)[0];
                           ^
TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
 at Function.keys (<anonymous>)
    at d:\magang\json_ke_word\node_modules\docx\build\index.cjs:18745:32 
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at resolve (d:\magang\json_ke_word\node_modules\docx\build\index.cjs:18743:1618743:16)
    at d:\magang\json_ke_word\node_modules\docx\build\index.cjs:18749:28 
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at resolve (d:\magang\json_ke_word\node_modules\docx\build\index.cjs:18743:1618743:16)
    at d:\magang\json_ke_word\node_modules\docx\build\index.cjs:18749:28 
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at resolve (d:\magang\json_ke_word\node_modules\docx\build\index.cjs:18743:1618743:16)

Node.js v20.11.1

here's my json structure:
{
    "bab": "II",
    "number": "",
    "part": null,
    "paragraph": null,
    "pasal": "pasal-2",
    "ref": null,
    "type": "",
    "content": ".",
    "additional_context": [],
    "context": ""
  },
  {
    "bab": null //if this bab (chapter) is null, the babParagraph will not appear
    "number": "",
    "part": null,
    "paragraph": null,
    "pasal": "pasal-2",
    "ref": null,
    "type": "",
    "content": ".",
    "additional_context": [],
    "context": ""
  },


also check if item.bab is undefined in your if statement
if (!!item.bab) {
do stuff
}

Thank you for your suggestion! I'll definitely check if item.bab is undefined in the if statement using the suggested approach. It's a good idea to ensure that all possible cases are covered. I appreciate your input!

Try this:
if (item.bab != ''){
}
or if (item && item.bab !== null){

}


Thanks man, I've tried this 'if (item.bab != ''){
}', it was ran without an err, but it likely doesn't have impact.
my Json key 'BAB':null is still appeared on my document file (i trying to parse that paragraph into document file
